# jquery stuck on 1 function based on input

Tags: jquery, forms, input

Selecting a radio button + x amount of checkboxes will give an error. 1st instance is button 1 + 5 checkboxes, if you click a 6th box, it gives an alert.

2nd function is button 2 + 10 checkboxes, but this simply gives the same error as button 1 and stops 10 boxes being clicked.

Code im using :

```
$("input[name='option[]']").on('change', function (e) {
    if ($("input[name='meals']").val() == 5 && $("input[name='option[]']:checked").length > 5)  {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 5");
    }
    else if ($("input[name='meals']").val() == 10 && $("input[name='option[]']:checked").length > 10)  {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 10");
    }
    else if ($("input[name='meals']").val() == 15 && $("input[name='option[]']:checked").length > 15)  {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 15");
    }
    else if ($("input[name='meals']").val() == 20 && $("input[name='option[]']:checked").length > 20)  {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 20");
    }
});
```

Any help would be great!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is because you're selecting *all* the `input[name='meals']` elements, not the one which is checked. Due to that `val()` is only being read from the first element in the collection, which is always `5`.

To fix this you need to use the `:checked` selector to get the chosen number of `meals`. You can also DRY up the logic by using that value in the `if` condition. Something like this:

```js
$("input[name='option[]']").on('change', function(e) {
  var maxAllowed = parseInt($("input[name='meals']:checked").val(), 10);

  if ($("input[name='option[]']:checked").length > maxAllowed) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    alert("allowed only " + maxAllowed);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="meals" value="5" checked="true" /> 5
</label><label>
  <input type="radio" name="meals" value="10" /> 10
</label><label>
  <input type="radio" name="meals" value="15" /> 15
</label><label>
  <input type="radio" name="meals" value="20" /> 20
</label><br /><br /><br />

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />
</div>
```